# Probability of winning sweepstakes when some information is not given

Tags: probability

I wanted to give my students an interesting probability problem, and found myself perplexed by it.

Below is the probability problem I came up with.

To win some prize a participant in a sweepstakes has to guess a four digit number. The designers of the sweepstakes created it in such a way that for every digit, any number from 0 to 9 is possible.

The creators of the sweepstakes did not inform well the participants about how the digits were selected. What is the probability that the first participant wins the prize if she thinks that no number can be repeated in the sequence?

Intuition: The probability of the first participant winning when understanding the rules is 1/10000 (1 out of 10^4 possibilities). By thinking that no number can be repeated, the participant may not consider numbers that may very well be the winning one. Thus, there probability of winning then should be lower than 1/10000.

Let W = win (chose winning number), C = winning number has no repeated digits. Then 
P(W) = P(W|C)P(C) + P(W|~C)P(~C)

Naturally, if the winning number had repeated digits, then the participant can't win due to the misunderstanding. Thus P(W|~C)=0 and

P(W) = P(W|C)P(C)

Now P(W|C) = 1/5040 (1 out of 10*9*8*7 possibilities) and P(C) = 5040/10000 (from 10*9*8*7/10000). Therefore P(W) = 1/5040 (5040/10000)=1/10000, same as if the participant did not misunderstand the rules.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Every guess has a $\frac 1{1000}$ chance however the person came up with it.  That's what "uniform" means.

Comment: Lulu, your response is too incomplete to tell if correct or not. I've come up with the proper answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What's incomplete?  Well, I should have written $\frac 1{10000}$.  Any guess has the same answer, doesn't matter how you came up with it.  Think of it this way:  Suppose I know the rules perfectly and guess $1234$.  You believe that the digits can not repeat and using that (false) rule you guess $1234$.  Do you believe that I have a greater chance of winning?

Comment: The problem with your intuition:  true your false rule lowers your chances in some cases (where the true value fails to honor your rule) but it increases your chances when it happens that the true value does honor your rule.  To take an extreme case, suppose I falsely believe that the answer has to be $1111$.  I will win with $0$ probability in the $\frac {9999}{10000}$ cases where my silly rule is wrong but I will win with probability $1$ in the $\frac 1{10000}$ cases where it is right.  Thus my probability is, of course, $\frac 1{10000}$.

Comment: To put this in perspective: What is the probability that I win if I select the number 8361? It is 1 in 10000, right? Now what is the probability that I win, if I mistakenly believe that the only number allowed is 8361? It's obviouslly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference how you come up with your guess, the probability of guessing correctly will always be $\frac 1{10^4}$.

To write this out in your case:  Let $p(n)$ be the probability that $n$ is the correct answer (so $p(n)=\frac 1{10^4}$ as we are assuming that the true distribution is uniform).  Let $\psi(n)$ be the probability that you guess $n$.

Now, under the false rule you have introduced, you are choosing uniformly at random from the $5040$ possible four digit numbers with distinct digits.  Thus:  $$  \psi(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac {1}{5040},  & \text{if $n$ has distinct digits} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ does not have distinct digits}
\end{cases}$$

The probability of guessing correctly is given by $$P=\sum_{n=0}^{9999} p(n)\psi(n)=\frac 1{10^4}\times \sum_{n=0}^{9999} \psi(n)$$

But that last sum is $\frac 1{5040}$ times the number of $n$ with distinct digits, hence the sum is $1$, making $P=\frac 1{10^4}$ as claimed.

The problem with your calculation comes when you write $P(C)=\frac {5040}{10000}$.  What does that mean?  $P(C)$ is, I believe,  the probability that, following the false rule, I choose a number consistent with the false rule...so $P(C)=1$.  If, instead, you meant that $P(C)$ was the probability that a uniformly random number in the range happened to satisfy the false rule, then $P(C)$ is what you say but in that case of course $P(\sim C)$ would not be $0$.  Indeed we'd have $P(\sim C)=\frac {4960}{10000}$ in which case your calculation would give the correct answer of $\frac 1{10^4}$.  Note that whatever you might have meant by $P(C)$ we should certainly have $P(C)+P(\sim C)=1$.

Comment: Lulu. Thank you for clarifying my error. You are correct, the probability that the first participant wins the prize if she thinks that no number can be repeated in the sequence is also 1/10000.

Comment: I would add for completeness a more explicit notation. We want P(W). Combining with your notation, P(W) is a function of P(W|N=n) and P(N=n). Yet W is independent of selection of N=n, and thus P(W)=P(W|N=n). My notation above is correct as the definition of C. Except that on my original value of P(W|C), 1/5040, was the correct one, not the modified one.

Comment: Well, I'm still not seeing your definition of $P(C)$.  As I say, for any event $C$, we must have $P(C)+P(\sim C)=1$.  With my understanding, we have $P(C)=1,P(\sim C)=0$.  Perfectly sensible.  I could, possibly, understand where you'd want $P(C)=.504,P(\sim C)=.496$.  But, really, the main point is what I started with:  it makes no difference how you come up with your guess, each guess has probability $\frac 1{10^4}$ of being correct.

Comment: Both procedures are correct. Yes, P(C) + P(~C)=1. But P(C) is not 1. As the C is defined, the probability that a number with no repeated digits is randomly selected is 5400/10000 (he can choose any of the 5,400 numbers with no digit repetition of the total 10,000 numbers that are possible)